# TypeScript: How to use Array.includes with possibly undefined value (optional chaining) on array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this example:

```
type SomeType = {
  paymentData?: {
    paymentMethod?: string;
  }
}

const someObj: SomeType = {};

const someTest = ['creditCard', 'payPal'].includes(someObj.paymentData?.paymentMethod);
```

This doesn't work in TypeScript because it infers the type of the array elements to be `string` so it requires the value used with the `includes` function to also be of type `string`, but `someObj.paymentData?.paymentMethod` is possibly undefined aka the type is `string | undefined`. I cannot use the non-null assertion operator (`!`) as it can't be used after optional chaining.

JavaScript-wise it's perfectly fine if the `includes` checks with `undefined`, just TypeScript is unhappy about it. What are nice ways to satisfy TypeScript here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to cast the array to an array of `string | undefined`. This is probably my preferred way as it doesn't leave any traces in the transpiled JavaScript code. Also it still prevents you from accidentally checking against e.g. a `number` which actually doesn't make sense.

```
const someTest = (['creditCard', 'payPal'] as (string | undefined)[]).includes(someObj.paymentData?.paymentMethod);
```

It is a bit verbose in the TypeScript code tho, so there are two more options:

Checking upfront if `someObj.paymentData?.paymentMethod` is defined:

```
const someTest = !!someObj.paymentData?.paymentMethod && ['creditCard', 'payPal'].includes(someObj.paymentData.paymentMethod);
```

Ensuring the value is always a string by falling back to an empty string in case of `undefined` using the nullish coalescing operator (`??`):

```
const someTest = ['creditCard', 'payPal'].includes(someObj.paymentData?.paymentMethod ?? '');
```

For further reference, here is a related thread on GitHub abut the typing of the `Array.includes` function: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)** - `!`:

```js
type SomeType = {
  paymentMethod?: string;
}

const someObj: SomeType = {};

const someTest = ['creditCard', 'payPal'].includes(someObj.paymentMethod!);
```

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gWAFBRRgCGISAdsALITAAWcAJgPwBcUAzsAE4CW5AcwDc%20AL758AYzjkunRBADyAIwBW7eElSQomLKJF4pMuRwXIIczAG0A5JO4RGvYAGFi3RrYA0UWyRAABWIAG1sAXQA6fkkQgFdGSwAKMyQVVUiAimpaBkYAQgBKISA)

Answer (score -4):

Ideally, the `paymentMethod` type would be defined. Usually this is defined by an API, if not, you should define it:

```
type PaymentMethod = 'creditCard' | 'payPal';

interface SomeType {
  paymentMethod?: PaymentMethod;
}

const someObj: SomeType = {};

const someTest = ['creditCard', 'payPal'].includes(someObj.paymentMethod);
```